# Cannot get XPath selector to work using Robocorp Selenium library

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, automation, css-selectors, robotframework

I am attempting web automation with a platform called Robocorp using the Selenium library.

When I run my program, I have no issues until I encounter this page where I am trying to get the program to click on the icon that says **SQL**.

I want the `<a>` element with the `@href` attribute.

Here are some (of many) XPaths I have tried that have all failed:

- `xpath://a[contains(@href,'sql_form.jsp')]`
- `xpath://*[text()='SQL']`
- `xpath://a[@target='frame2]`

Snapshot of the element:

[image: UI element]

I circled the element in red ^^^

I cannot get the selector to be recognized on this page. I have tried adding delays, waiting until the element is active, waiting until the element is visible, etc.

Nothing seems to work.

[image: Element data from 'inspect']

Here is an image of the elements I am trying to select.
(The link in the href element takes me to the page I am trying to access).

I thought that the third one would for sure work but is still failing.

I am using a platform called Robocorp which only needs the raw selector to work (CSS or XPath)

[image: VS Code - Robocorp program]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To identify the element with text as ***SQL*** you can use you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *`Wait Until Element Is Visible`*:

  ```
  Wait Until Element Is Visible    xpath=//a[starts-with(@href, 'sql_form.jsp') and @target='frame2']/font[text()='SQL']    10  seconds
  ```
- Using *`Wait Until Element Is Enabled`*:

  ```
  Wait Until Element Is Enabled    xpath=//a[starts-with(@href, 'sql_form.jsp') and @target='frame2']/font[text()='SQL']    10  seconds
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to click a row that has javascript on click event in RIDE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52815484/7429447)
- [Robot Framework: Wait Until Element Is Visible vs. Element Should Be Visible, which one is better to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53152697/7429447)

Comment: Thanks for the useful information, however, I am still getting an error saying the selector cannot be found:  Element with locator 'xpath=//a[starts-with(@href, 'sql_form.jsp') and @target='frame2']/font[text()='SQL']' not found.

Answer (score 2):

I was unaware that iframe needed to be handled differently or that it even existed
https://robocorp.com/docs/development-guide/browser/how-to-work-with-iframes

I first needed to switch frames.